# Can 'this' ever be null in Javascript

Tags: javascript, null, this

I have a function along the lines of the following:

```
    doSomething: function () {
        var parent = null;

        if (this === null) {
            parent = 'some default value';
        } else {
            parent = this.SomeValue();
        }
    }
```

**Could parent ever be set to 'some default value'** or is the check for null superfluous?

Alternatively, what if I used the less restrictive:

```
    doSomething: function () {
        var parent = this ? this.SomeValue() : 'some default value';
    }
```

**Could parent ever be set to 'some default value' in this case?**

Answer (score 38, accepted):

In non-strict mode, `this` has undergone an `Object(this)` transformation, so it's always truthy. The exceptions are `null` and `undefined` which map to the global object. So `this` is never `null` and always truthy, making both checks superfluous.

In strict mode, however, `this` can be anything so in that case you'd have to watch out. But then again you have to opt in for strict mode yourself, so if you don't do that there are no worries.

```
(function() {               return this; }).call(null); // global object
(function() { "use strict"; return this; }).call(null); // null
```

The [specification](http://es5.github.com/#x15.3.4.4) of ES5 says:

> The thisArg value is passed **without modification** as the this value. This is a change from Edition 3, where a undefined or null thisArg is replaced with **the global object** and **ToObject** is applied to all other values and that result is passed as the this value.

Comment: It should be noted that attempting to call the "SomeValue()" function on an object without such a property might be cause for a *little* worry.

Comment: Well, technically it hasn't always undergone `Object(this)`, since if it is an object, it doesn't, and more importantly, if it was initially `null` or `undefined` then it doesn't either, it's just directly set to the global object.

Comment: @davin: Actually for an object it doesn't matter whether it does (`Object(obj) === obj`), but as for your second point, you're entirely correct.

Comment: I agree it doesn't matter, but the spec's algorithm doesn't specify that it undergoes Object coercion, so I was nitpicking (which wasn't very polite); i.e. I agree that the values are the same, but the procedure `Object(this)` would not be performed in such a case (http://es5.github.com/#x10.4.3).

Comment: +1, but the example is rather contrived. In strict mode, `this` will be null in some "normal" cases - see the "Eliminates this coercion" section of http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2012/03/13/its-time-to-start-using-javascript-strict-mode/

Comment: @Gabe Moothart: Practically `this` will indeed never be `null` because you need to explicitly set it. Reading between the lines however, it looks like the OP also cares for `undefined` because it'd throw a similar error when accessing the function on it.

Comment: @pimvdb you're right, I wasn't properly distinguishing between `null` and `undefined`. Oh, the wonders of javascript :-)

Answer (score 2):

Although not a direct answer to your question.. in a browser 'this' will, by default, refer to the 'window' object. On nodejs it will refer to the global object.

I'm not sure if there's ever a case where it could be null, but it would at the very least be unusual.

Comment: Welp.. I'll leave my answer because it may be useful, but pimvdb has the better answer :)

Answer (score 2):

The `this` keyword shouldn't ever be null, but it might not be what you expect. You can end up referencing the `window` object if you're not careful.

In your case, I believe `this` should refer to the `doSomething` function.

```
var myObject = {
    myMethod: function() {
        console.log(this);
    }
};

myObject.myMethod(); // prints out a reference to the myMethod function
```

Here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lfyk8/1/).

Answer (score 1):

You can see what occurs if you try to force Javascript to use a null scope in any browser.  I made an example here:

http://jsfiddle.net/rXsWj/

In short, this empirically proves that the browser changes 'null' to 'window' on the fly.  If  instead you change null to 'a', you'll see an alert of 'a' like you would expect. Code from link as reference:

```
function a() {
    alert(this)
}

a.apply(null)
```

​

Answer (score 0):

No. The value of `this` will never be the text `'some default value'`.

Answer (score 0):

`this` can not be null. if it was null, then you couldn't be in method scope.