# Is this judgement essential in the Array.prototype.filter

Tags: javascript, arrays

I found that there is an not essential judgement in many methods displayed on the website of developer.mozilla.
URL:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

You can forward to the "Polyfill" section.

There always exists a judgement like following code:

```
Array.prototype.filter = function(fun /*, thisArg */)
{
    "use strict";

    if (this === void 0 || this === null)
      throw new TypeError();
    ...
}
```

Not only filter method, but also Array.prototype.every(), Array.prototype.map().
Such as:

```
Array.prototype.map = function (fun /*, thisp */) {
   if (this === void 0 || this === null) { throw TypeError(); 
   ...
}
```

I do not know in which cases the result of the condition will return true and then throw a "TypeError".
In my opinion, this judgement is not essential, should be removed.
What do you think? 
And this judgement is for what?

Comment: "Judgement" is probably not the word you're looking for. Do you mean "condition"?

Comment: Yes, I mean the "condition"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I  do not know in which cases the result of the condition will return
>   true and then throw a "TypeError".

Answer:

```
Array.prototype.filter = function(fun /*, thisArg */){
  console.log('okay',this==null);
}
Array.prototype.filter.call(null);
Array.prototype.filter.call(undefined);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I do not understand that you just use a calling method, how would it prove that the condition will return true?

Comment: @edmond It could be used on array like objects such as:  getElementsByTagName https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.getElementsByTagName Add the condition and you'll see it's true

Comment: thanks for your patience. I saw the URL you give to me. Could you explain it to me more detailed? Do you mean that the getElementByTagName method call the Array.prototype.filter?

Comment: I saw your edit. I made a try on chrome in debug mode. But 'this == null' still return false. because the "this" refer to the Window Object.

Comment: @edmond because getElementByTagName returns an array like object that has length and [index] but doesn't inherit from Array (it doesn't have a filter method) you have to use Array.prototype. filter.call(objectReturnedFromGetElements,...

Comment: Thanks for your explain. I cannot expand the your whole comment, maybe it is too long, is there a way to see your whole comment?

Comment: I made a test using getElementsByTagName, but condition still return false.

Comment: You are correct, my example doesn't have this as null as it's in non strict mode but it can be null or undefined:        http://stackoverflow.com/a/9739856/1641941. Sorry my previous comment actually ended with dots.

Answer (score 1):

`this` refers to the array itself.

`void 0` returns `undefined` and can not be overwritten (while `undefined` can - pre ES5).

The check is used to determine that the prototype method is used on something that actually exists i.e. is not undefined nor null.

If you look at [MDN's](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) latest polyfill, they simply use:

```
if (this == null) {
   throw new TypeError(" this is null or not defined");
}
```

since `null == undefined` is `true`.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I found that MDN's latest polyfill has been updated to what you see. In my opinion, "undefined.filter" or "null.filter" will not turn into the Array.prototype.filter(), so the condition is not essential.