# Why doesn't this debounce function work?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a debounce function, and I do not understand why it doesn't debounce.

I first created this function here:

```js
const debounce = function throttleFunctionCalls(func, wait, immediate) {
  let timeout
  return () => {
    const context = this
    const args = arguments
    const later = () => {
      timeout = null
      if (!immediate) func.apply(context, args)
    }
    const callNow = immediate && !timeout
    clearTimeout(timeout)
    timeout = setTimeout(later, wait)
    if (callNow) func.apply(context, args)
  }
}

const testFunction = () => console.log('test')

setInterval(() => debounce(testFunction(), 10000), 100)
```

But, it logs every 100ms, so it is not working as intended.

I tried a completely different debounce function, which is arguably better due to spreading args rather than using `arguments`, but it suffers the same problem:

```js
function debounce(func, wait) {
  let timeout
  return function throttleFunctionCalls(...args) {
    const context = this
    clearTimeout(timeout)
    timeout = setTimeout(() => func.apply(context, args), wait)
  }
}

const testFunction = () => console.log('test')

setInterval(() => debounce(testFunction(), 10000), 100)
```

I don't have a real scenario to debounce right now, so I'm having trouble testing it in its natural habitat.

Is there something wrong with the `setInterval` approach?

It seems like its awareness of `timeout` is getting lost every time. Can anyone shed some light?

[edit]

As charlietfl pointed out in a comment below, I should not be evoking the function. Oops, I definitely shouldn't be doing that, but I tried it before making this question and it didn't work, so for some reason, I ended up with what is above.

```js
function debounce(func, wait) {
  let timeout
  return function throttleFunctionCalls(...args) {
    const context = this
    clearTimeout(timeout)
    timeout = setTimeout(() => func.apply(context, args), wait)
  }
}

const testFunction = (value) => console.log('test: ' + value)

setInterval(() => debounce(testFunction, 1), 100)
```

This above hangs the thread when I just pass reference function as a reference. I am also uncertain how to pass the actual function arguments into it unless it picks them up by closure.

Can anyone show me a functional example that can pass an arbitrary value in with testFunction()?

Comment: You are invoking `testFunction` when you call debounce() instead of passing the function name as reference

Comment: Yes I had a feeling of that, but I tried `debounce(testFunction, 1000)` and it was still acting weird. Thanks, let me try more with that.

Comment: It is just hanging when I pass it as reference.

Comment: I can hook you up with a guy that sells semicolon keys

Comment: Lol, that could be a reason, but I use babel which adds them back, after which we are talking about `ASI`, after which we are talking about breaking libraries, but before all, I would like to hear your reasoning with respect to 2018.

Comment: You've guessed right. To pass arbitrary arguments to a callback let it pick them up by closure: `debounce(function(){testfunction(many,arguments,to,process)},1000)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's look through your last example:

```
function debounce(func, wait) {
  let timeout
  return function throttleFunctionCalls(...args) {
    const context = this
    clearTimeout(timeout)
    timeout = setTimeout(() => func.apply(context, args), wait)
  }
}
```

You've defined a function `debounce` that takes in a function and a wait time and returns a function. So far so good.

```
const testFunction = (value) => console.log('test: ' + value)
```

Next you've defined a function `testFunction` that takes in a value and logs it.

```
setInterval(() => debounce(testFunction, 1), 100)
```

Here's a problem. As the first argument to `setInterval` you have created a new function that takes in no arguments and returns the result of calling `debounce` on `testFunction`. As stated above, `debounce` will simply return a function. Effectively, once every 100 milliseconds, you're just returning a new function rather than executing the logging logic.

Here's a slightly more condensed version of your code using arrow functions:

```
const debounce = (func, wait) => {
    let timeout;
    return (...args) => {
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        timeout = setTimeout(() => func.apply(this, args), wait);
    };
};
```

Again we'll construct a test function:

```
const testFunction = (value) => {
    console.log(`test: ${value}`);
};
```

This time we'll make a debounced version of the test function with a wait time of 1ms:

```
const debouncedTest1 = debounce(testFunction, 1);
```

And now we can set an interval to execute it. This is also one of the ways you can pass arguments to the test function:

```
setInterval(debouncedTest1, 200, 'foo');
```

This will log 'foo' every 200ms. Technically the first log message will come up 201ms after the `setInterval` call: 200ms for the interval, and 1ms for the debounce logic. No debouncing will occur here because the interval is longer than the debounce wait period.

Trying this the other way around will not output anything:

```
const debouncedTest2 = debounce(testFunction, 200);
setInterval(debouncedTest2, 1, 'bar');
```

After 1ms, the interval timeout will attempt to call `debouncedTest2`. The debounce logic will cause it to begin waiting 200ms before executing the log. But 1ms later, the next interval timeout will fire, which will push back that debounce interval again. This continues indefinitely, and you never see any messages.

In truth, trying to test debounce with `setInterval` may not be the greatest approach.

Let's just try a more human-observable wait period and manually call the debounced function several times in rapid succession:

```
const debouncedTest3 = debounce(testFunction, 1000);

debouncedTest3('hi');
debouncedTest3('hello');
debouncedTest3('hey');
```

If you attempt to run this test, it will wait about one second and then output `test: hey`. The first two calls were thrown away by the debounce logic.

On a tangent, another way to pass the arguments to your test function is to bake them into the debounced function call. There are multiple ways you could approach this. Here are two examples:

```
const debouncedTest4 = debounce(testFunction, 1000);
const debouncedTest4WithArg = () => debouncedTest4('test arg');

debouncedTest4WithArg();
debouncedTest4WithArg();
debouncedTest4WithArg();

const debouncedTest5 = debounce(() => testFunction('test arg'), 1000);

debouncedTest5();
debouncedTest5();
debouncedTest5();
```

Comment: Thanks. My true problem was I didn't realize it was just restarting the `setTimeout` every time, so it wouldn't ever be able to complete because I was killing the script. All the answers in here are very useful, but I appreciated how you stepped through the workflow and included mention of passing args.

Comment: I spun up a different example that used a for loop, and now I can see how it's working very clearly not even to mention your examples which are very clear.

Answer (score 2):

In the call

> ```
> setInterval(() => debounce(testFunction(), 10000), 100)
> ```

you a) pass the return value of `testFunction()` - `undefined` - to `debounce`, instead of the function itself and b) never call the function that is returned by `debounce`. This is how the invocation should look like:

```
const debouncedTestFunction = debounce(testFunction, 10000)
setInterval(() => debouncedTestFunction(), 100)
```

or in short

```
setInterval(debounce(testFunction, 10000), 100)
```

---

That said, you are misusing arrow syntax. Arrow functions do not have their own [`arguments`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30935336/1048572) and [`this` values](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34361379/1048572) but inherit them lexically, so your code doesn't work. It needs to be

```
function debounce(func, wait, immediate) {
  let timeout
  return function() {
//       ^^^^^^^^^^
    const later = () => {
      timeout = null
      if (!immediate) func.apply(this, arguments)
    }
    const callNow = immediate && !timeout
    clearTimeout(timeout)
    timeout = setTimeout(later, wait)
    if (callNow) func.apply(this, arguments)
  }
}
```

Comment: Ahh.. do you mean `do not` instead of `do`?

Comment: @slebetman I think I meant to put focus on *lexical*, but you're right it was confusing

Answer (score 1):

The code is more or less complete but is being called incorrectly. `debounce` is returning a function that has been debounced. You have to call the debounced function instead of the function supplied to `debounce`, or `debounce` itself multiple times.

Note that for the original function to be called the first time, calls to the debounced function must stop for longer than the debounce period. The logic could be made more complicated to let calls through every now and then even if they never stop - but that is not generally how hardware debounce circuitry works.

Here's an example of your code in action:

```js
function debounce(func, wait) {
  let timeout
  return function throttleFunctionCalls(...args) {
    const context = this
    clearTimeout(timeout)
    timeout = setTimeout(() => func.apply(context, args), wait)
  }
}

const testFunction = (string) => console.log('test ' + string)

const debouncedTestFunction = debounce( testFunction, 500);

setTimeout( debouncedTestFunction, 100, "first call");
setTimeout( debouncedTestFunction, 200, "second call");
setTimeout( debouncedTestFunction, 300, "third call");
// and pause for a while
setTimeout( debouncedTestFunction, 900, "fourth call");
```

Because of the `setTimeout` delays chosen for a 500ms debounce, the expected result is that the third and fourth calls should get through, but the first and second will not.

---

Followup:

Credit to @charlietfl in question comment to not call `testFunction` when a reference to the function is required.

You were wise to abandon the use of the `arguments` array in the second version of `debounce` posted. As noted in other answers `arguments` it is not supported in arrow functions but the failure mode would have been interesting - the `debounce` function expression starts with `function` which introduces `arguments` into function scope. The arrow function returned would then use the `arguments` value of the `debounce` call as in this example:

```js
function test() {
  return ()=>arguments[0]
}
console.log( (test("test argument"))("call argument"));
```

Quite a debugging mess.  It would be of interest to check how babel translates the arrow function usage of the `arguments` value.

A second concern is that the (second) `debounce` function effectively returns a bound function (in the manner of `Function.prototype.bind`) but records the `this` value seen within the `debounce` function whatever that may be. May I suggest either to add a `thisValue` argument to `debounce` or use `null` for the `thisValue` when calling `apply`. (The exact effect of `null` depends on whether the [called code is in strict mode](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9739806/5217142)).

Comment: Thanks for the response. Check out https://babeljs.io/repl/ and paste the sample code in and you can see how it might be transpiled. I would paste the output but it will look gross in the comment box.